# How can I run a Typescript script on Node without importing anything from it?

Tags: node.js, typescript, node-modules

Typescript handbook mentions [scripts, as opposed to modules](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html#red-flags):

> Conversely, a file without any top-level import or export declarations is treated as a script whose contents are available in the global scope (and therefore to modules as well).

I have a couple of scripts that don't import anything, just iteratively do some work, like this:

```
// script.ts

console.log('test')
```

I want to run them all one by one from the `index.ts` (which is defined as main in package.json). However, when I just import them:

```
// index.ts

console.log(1)
import {} from './script'
console.log(2)
```

It does not do anything in the compiled JS:

```
// index.js (compiled)

"use strict";
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
console.log(1);
// << shouldn't there be something here?
console.log(2);
//# sourceMappingURL=index.js.map
```

How can I properly call that script so it root content runs when I run my compiled index.js?

Comment: Import like this: `import './script'`

Comment: @chautelly that solved my issue, thank you! Care to submit it as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Scripts are imported like this:

```
import './script'
```

without using *from*

Comment: In this case path ckecking is not working, for example import 'nothing';